# 空白で区切られた入力を処理したい

Tags: c++

C++でモールス信号を製作しようと考えています。ただ、空白を区切って出力ができません。どのように空白で区切ってそれぞれのモールスを変換できるでしょうか。

一度だけの入力と出力なら受け付けていました。ただし、空白を開けてもう一度続けてモールスを入力してもそのままのモールスが返ってきました。どうすれば空白ごとで変換できるでしょうか。お願いします。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string morce;//入力するモールスの変数
    string alpha;//変換したときのアルファベットの入れ物の変数

    cout << "暗号を入力してください\n";
    getline(cin, morce);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {//それぞれ入力されたモールスを空白が押されるまでの変換

            if (morce == "・－")
            {
                morce = 'a';
            }

            if (morce == "－・・・")
            {
                morce = 'b';
            }


    }

    cout << morce << endl;//すべて入力し終わったとき出力

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 解決マークは付いていませんが、これらの記事が参考になるかも。[C++ Morse to english](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013166/9014308), [C Program to decode Morse code to text using spaces to detect words or sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51581771/9014308), [Morse Code Converter in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28045172/9014308), [Decoding Morse Code with strtok in binary tree - garbage output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23419077/9014308)

Comment: 過去の質問について放置せず、[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) に沿った対応をお願いします。もちろん、解決していない場合は、何が不足しているのかを質問文などに補足してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問に提示されたソースコードは、以下の問題があります。

- 先ず問題なのは、`for`文の中でどれも入力された文字列全体を判定している(`if (morce == "・－")`等)ことです。
- そして次に問題なのは、入力された文字列自身を置き換えている(`morce = 'a';`等)ことです。
- これは副次的な問題として、変数`alpha`が`変換したときのアルファベットの入れ物の変数`とコメントされて定義されているのに、何にも使われていないことにつながります。
  最後の出力も変数`morce`が使われています。
- それから、`for`ループの制御が`0`から`100`未満となっているけれども、それ自身には意味が無い処理であることです。

---

その上で、質問の主題である「空白で区切られた入力を処理したい」については、コメントで紹介した記事の最初の回答にあるように、`stringstream`を使うことで実現出来るでしょう。
[C++ Morse to english](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013166/9014308)
該当部分

> ```
> #include <sstream>
> // ... 途中省略 ...
>     stringstream mors(morse_code);
>     string letter;
>
>     while (mors >> letter) {
>         vector<string>::iterator it;
>         it = find(Morse.begin(), Morse.end(), letter);
>         size_t dist = distance(Morse.begin(), it);
>         cout << Letter[dist] << endl;
>     }
> ```

ソースコードだけ提示して何も説明が無いためか、downvoteされていますが、この辺の記事でstringstreamからの入力は空白で区切られて通知されるとあります。
[文字列を区切り文字で分割する (istringstream)](https://maku77.github.io/cpp/string/split.html)
[【C++入門】stringstreamで文字列を操作する方法](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/51234)
[stringstreamを使ってみたんだよ](https://chakku.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/02/15/155106)

質問のソースコード該当部分は以下のようになるでしょう。
モールス信号かどうか判定している各`if`も色々と工夫した方が良いですが、今は置いておきます。

```
#include <sstream>
// ... 途中省略 ...
    cout << "暗号を入力してください\n";
    getline(cin, morce);

    stringstream ss(morce);
    string token;

    while (ss >> token) {
        if (token == "・－")
        {
            alpha += 'a';
        }
        if (token == "－・・・")
        {
            alpha += 'b';
        }
        // ... 途中省略 ...
    }
    cout << alpha << endl;//すべて入力し終わったとき出力
```